# TIme difference within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Loaded time data from excel into python and I want to manipulate the time to reflect continuous experiment. here is my data:

**time =**

```
10:21:00
10:22:00
10:23:00
10:24:00
10:25:00
10:26:00
10:27:00
10:28:00
10:29:00
10:30:00
10:31:00
10:32:00
11:00:00
11:01:00
11:02:00
11:03:00
11:04:00
11:05:00
```

IF I subtract the time difference gives a value. however, at `11.00:00`, the time difference is large because the experiment was stopped but I want it to reflect continuous values as follows:

**time difference:**

```
0
0.016666667
0.033333333
0.05
0.066666667
0.083333333
0.1
0.116666667
0.133333333
0.15
0.166666667
0.183333333
0.2
**0.216666667**
0.233333333
0.25
0.266666667
0.283333333
0.3
```

I don't want actual difference at 11:00:00 that will give the following data:

```
0
0.016666667
0.033333333
0.05
0.066666667
0.083333333
0.1
0.116666667
0.133333333
0.15
0.166666667
0.183333333
0.2
**0.666666667**
0.683333333
0.7
0.716666667
0.733333333
0.75
```

as a result, I wrote this code:

```
import datetime as datetime
t = df.time.values

tr=pd.to_datetime(t, format = '%H:%M:%S')

yt = pd.Series(tr)

td = pd.to_timedelta(yt)

u=(td - td.shift()).fillna(0)
```

not working at all...

Comment: With what values are you subtracting?

Comment: Please, provide [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: subtracting the time within the columns.